# Spring Batch Job stops running after Migrating to Spring Boot 2

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

Working on an issue where I have a Spring batch job with code that looks like this:

```
@Bean
public Job job(@Qualifier("fileSyncStep") Step step1) {
    return jobBuilderFactory.get("myJob").start(step1).build();
}
```

Before migrating to Spring Boot 2 this job worked perfectly fine. After migrating to Spring Boot2 the application still loaded up fine like before, except now the job would not actually run. After spending hours trying to debug, by dumb luck I found it would run once if I changed the name of the job to something unique. So if I changed the name of `"myJob"` to something new like `"myJob2"` or `"newJobName"` it would run one time.

Can anyone please explain what is going wrong and how to fix this!? I don't want to have to write code that generates a unique name everytime. I have the logs at complete debug level and no indication at all as to what is going on.

Comment: Any exceptions/output you can provide from your migration?

Comment: No exceptions at all! In the end the job just doesn't run. I even added in a JobExecutionListener and the beforeJob method never gets called.